# Удаление повторяющихся слов из строки(std::string) в C++

Tags: c++, строки

К примеру, есть вот такое дело:

```
string str = "int double int";
```

Я уже написал функцию удаления, но там костыли, и она мне очень не нравится из-за громоздкости и т.д. Подскажите как можно элегантнее, что-ли, с использованием последних новшеств удалить повторяющиеся слова. То есть, чтобы на выходе было вот это: "int double".

Comment: @Abyx, в текущей строке есть 3 слова: int, double, int.

Comment: @Koka_LV На будущее, я бы в вопросе точнее требования писал. Сейчас непонятно, как нужно обращаться со знаками препинания и т.п.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ответ, который мне подошел:

```
void RemoveDublicate(string str)
```

{

```
istringstream ss(str);

unordered_set<string> hsh;

string word;

do
{
    ss >> word;

    while (hsh.find(word) == hsh.end())
    {
        cout << word << " ";

        hsh.insert(word);
    }

} while (ss);
```

}

Comment: Вы делаете две итерации, а можете одну, если замените внутренний `while` на `if`

Answer (score 2):

1. Ваш вариант решения нужно помещать в вопрос, а не выдавать как
   ответ, тем более что оно ошибочное(плюс попытка в каждом шаге  цикла
   проходить по всей последовательности методом `find`.
2. Ваша функция принимает копию и не возвращает ничего, так что после
   вызова функции ваша строка не изменится, а вы не сможете
   воспользоваться кодом, выполненной в функции.  Функция
   должна возвращать строку или же принимать ссыльку.
3. Если вы пишете функцию(класс), не используйте заранее все
   пространство имен, чтобы не засорять программу лишными именами из
   жтого пространства и чтобы им мог кто то еще пользоваться(или вы
   сами в другом месте).

Если не существенно сохранять количество пробелов между словами(пробелов может быть больше одного), то можно решать например так:

```
void RemoveDublicate(std::string& str) {    
    std::istringstream is(str);
    std::unordered_set<string> w;
    std::string s;
    while (is >> s)
        w.emplace(s + ' '); //слово с пробелом
    s.clear(); //воспользуемся дальше этим обьектом
    str = std::accumulate(w.begin(), w.end(), s);   
}
int main() {
    std::string s = "int double int";
    RemoveDublicate(s);
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала разбейте строку на лексемы

```
template<class InIt, class OutIt, class T, class F>
InIt split(InIt it, InIt end_it, OutIt out_it, T split_val, F func) {
    while(it != end_it) {
        auto slince_end{std::find(it, end_it, split_val)};
        *out_it++ = func(it, slince_end);
        if(slince_end == end_it) {
            return end_it;
        }
        it = std::next(slince_end);
    }
    return it;
}

std::string val{"a,b,c,d,e,f"};
auto bunfunc{[](auto it_a, auto it_b){return std::string{it_a, it_b};}};
std::vector<std::string> v;
split(std::begin(val), std::end(val), std::back_inserter(v), ',', bunfunc);
```

Далее можно просто отсортировать ее используя std::sort

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

и затем убрать дубликаты

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(last, v.end());
```

Comment: Решение на хэш таблицах будет быстрее.